# Applying a snapshot in Hyper-V WMI V2 from C#

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am trying to replicate the following PowerShell in C#:

```
# Details from here are not particularly important but needed for full sample
$vms = gwmi -namespace "root\virtualization\v2" Msvm_ComputerSystem
$vm = $vms[3]
$snapshot = ($vm.GetRelated("Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData") | Where { $_.ElementName -eq "SnapshotName" })[0]
# end unimportant 

$VMSS = Get-WMiObject -class Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService -namespace root\virtualization\v2
$VMSS.ApplySnapshot($snapshot, $null)
```

This code works fine - the snapshot applies as expected.

I have no problem getting the `Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData` instance or a `Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshostService` instance in C#.  However, I can't seem to get the call to `ApplySnapshot` right - no matter what I give it I get an `InvalidOperationException`.  I'm using generated WMI code from Visual Studio for the call:

```
public uint ApplySnapshot(ref System.Management.ManagementPath Job, System.Management.ManagementPath Snapshot) {
    if ((isEmbedded == false)) {
        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject inParams = null;
        inParams = PrivateLateBoundObject.GetMethodParameters("ApplySnapshot");
        // following line has been through variations as well with no change -
        // commenting it out, setting to null
        inParams["Job"] = ((System.Management.ManagementPath)(Job)).Path;
        inParams["Snapshot"] = ((System.Management.ManagementPath)(Snapshot)).Path;
        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject outParams = PrivateLateBoundObject.InvokeMethod("ApplySnapshot", inParams, null);
        Job = ((System.Management.ManagementPath)(outParams.Properties["Job"].Value));
        return System.Convert.ToUInt32(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
    }
    else {
        return System.Convert.ToUInt32(0);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to pass for the `Job` parameter either, since we get a job back - it's very unusual to have a `ref` for that instead of an `out` but I've tried a bunch of different variations around that (including setting the parameter to `null` and not setting it at all) with no luck.  I've also tried setting `inParams[Job]` to `null` with no luck for that either.

What should I change to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are passing in the job to start with when it is an outbound parameter. That parameter will return from the invocation. Something like..

```
ManagementBaseObject inParams = null;

inParams = PrivateLateBoundObject.GetMethodParameters("ApplySnapshot");
inParams["Snapshot"] = ((System.Management.ManagementPath)(Snapshot)).Path;

ManagementBaseObject outParams = PrivateLateBoundObject.InvokeMethod("ApplySnapshot", inParams, null);

// i left this as i assume this is vs generated though this isn't how i would normally
// get my jobs back.
Job = ((ManagementPath)(outParams.Properties["Job"].Value));

return Convert.ToUInt32(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
```

Comment: I found there was a bug in previous code that meant that `PrivateLateBoundObject` wasn't set properly, and that was the source of the failure.  I also had some communications with Microsoft who confirmed a MOF file bug - `Job` is marked as `IN OUT` when it should just be `OUT` - which is why the generated code is `ref` and not `out`.  Ultimately although this answer is not _the_ answer in my case, it's accurate enough information nonetheless.